# How to continue Jenking stage on failure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I would like to run pipeline with 2 stages. If any of the stage is failed, next stage should be started (not skipped). Currently if 1st stage is failed, next stage will be skipped.

Thank you for any help.

```
pipeline {
options { buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5', artifactNumToKeepStr: '5')) }
agent { label 'docker_gradle' }
triggers {
    cron(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'develop' || env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master' ? '@daily' : '')
}
stages {
    stage('Init') {
        steps {
            sh 'chmod +x gradlew'
        }
    }
    stage('task1') {
        when { anyOf { branch 'feature/*'; branch 'develop' }}
        steps {
            container(name: 'gradle') {
                sh 'gradle clean task1'
            }
        }
    }
    stage('task2') {
        when { anyOf { branch 'feature/*'; branch 'develop' }}
        steps {
            container(name: 'gradle') {
                sh 'gradle clean task2'
            }
        }
    }
}

post {
    always {
        script {
            currentBuild.result = currentBuild.result ?: 'SUCCESS'
            cucumber buildStatus: 'UNSTABLE',
                    failedFeaturesNumber: 1,
                    failedScenariosNumber: 1,
                    skippedStepsNumber: 1,
                    failedStepsNumber: 1,
                    reportTitle: 'Reoport',
                    fileIncludePattern: '**/cucumber.json',
                    sortingMethod: 'ALPHABETICAL',
                    trendsLimit: 100
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1.You can change sh 'gradle clean task1' to

```
sh 'gradle clean task1 || true'
```

This will make sh return success even if sh scrip fails

2.You can also use try catch

Check this link: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#flow-control

for example:

```
stage("task1"){
      steps {
        script {
          try {
            sh 'gradle clean task1'
          } catch (err) {
            echo err.getMessage()
          }
        }
      }
    }
```